# What is the limit of $(1+(\frac23)^n)^{1/n}$?

Tags: limits, power-series, euler-mascheroni-constant

I was studying complex analysis and wanted to find the radius of convergence of the power series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2^n+3^n}{4^n+5^n}z^n$$
I used 'root test' and had to find the limit of the form
$$\left(1+\left(\frac23\right)^n\right)^{1/n}$$
(say, it's $a_n$) It's pretty similar to the definition of $e$. And since $(\frac23)^n$ converges to $0$ more rapidly than $\frac1n$ does, I think $a_n$ must converges to $1$.
Moreover, the expression like
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\left(1+\left(\frac23\right)^n\right)^{(\frac32)^n}\right]^{(\frac23)^n\times\frac1n}$$
is of the form
$$e^0$$
and it equals to $1$.
So I can conclude that the radius of convergence is $\frac53$.

But I can't give the precise reason for $a_n$ being approaching $1$.
Can anybody give me the right procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way to show it converges to $1$ is to note that for $a \gt 1, n \gt 1, a^{1/n} \lt a$  Then you can say $1 \lt \left(1+\left(\frac23\right)^n\right)^{1/n} \lt\left(1+\left(\frac23\right)^n\right) \to 1$

Comment: Wow. I understand it immediately thanks.

Comment: Thank you for answering me. But looking it again, I think it is too trivial question. It is completely different from the definition of e. Can I delete the whole question?

Comment: You are correct it is quite different from the definition of $e$, but it is still a reasonable limit question.  I would leave it

Comment: I see. Have a good day, thanks.